# vercel nextjs deployment build error: How to debug?

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'm a beginner deploying a basic nextjs app with vercel.

This error is occurring in the node_modules files, not in any code that I have written.

How should I go about debugging this?

````
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'page')
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:223:40
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:222:43
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1168:21
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1044:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:65:29)```
````

Comment: Is that the full error stack trace? Does the error mention what page/file in the Next.js project causes it?

Comment: It doesn't mention a page in the app that is causing the error, but I've now deduced that it is coming from a dynamic route. When I remove the pages/[id] file, the app builds successfully. Do you see cause here?


export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  return {
    props: { data },
  };
};

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  let paths = data.filter(entry => !!entry.name).map((architect) => {
    return {
      params: {
        name: architect.name.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-"),
      },
    };
  });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}

Comment: Please edit the code into the question. Can you also add the React code for that page?